# Hazelcast asynchronous client - checking 'CLIENT_CONNECTED' state

Tags: java, hazelcast

I need to check if Hazelcast client is connected to cluster.

The way I'm trying to do this

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new XmlClientConfigBuilder(xmlConfigurationFileName).build();

ClientStateListener clientStateListener = new ClientStateListener(clientConfig);
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

final boolean connected = clientStateListener.isConnected();
final boolean started = clientStateListener.isStarted();
```

isStarted method return true, but isConnected always false. Between isConnected checking I'm putting and getting data from server cluster, so client is connected for sure (which I can see also in logs) - also when I'm setting asynchronous on false (async-start="false") then isConnected is returning true.

LifecycleServiceImpl Hazelcast class contains in fireLifecycleEvent method (called in HZ when status is changing) such code

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (LifecycleListener lifecycleListener : lifecycleListeners.values()) {
            lifecycleListener.stateChanged(lifecycleEvent);
        }
    }
});
```

In synchronous mode run was called each time (twice STARTING->STARTED and STARTED->CLIENT_CONNECTED). In asynchronous only once (STARTING->STARTED).

Hazelcast version 3.12.1.

This is whole configuration (server discovery strategy by tcp-ip)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
              http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.12.xsd">

    <group>
        <name>hazelcast-group</name>
    </group>

    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX</address>
            <address>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX</address>
            <address>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX</address>
            <address>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX</address>
        </cluster-members>
    </network>

    <connection-strategy async-start="true" reconnect-mode="ASYNC">
        <connection-retry enabled="true">
            <initial-backoff-millis>2000</initial-backoff-millis>
            <max-backoff-millis>60000</max-backoff-millis>
            <multiplier>3</multiplier>
            <fail-on-max-backoff>false</fail-on-max-backoff>
            <jitter>0.5</jitter>
        </connection-retry>
    </connection-strategy>

</hazelcast-client>
```

What should be done to force statusChange for CLIENT_CONNECTED state ?

Comment: In order to have the client object in CONNECTED state, you need to set the client connection strategy to `sync`. Otherwise, `HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);` will execute non-blocking, thus, give you a client object which has not connected to the cluster yet.

Comment: Can you please share the logs? The state listener should be returning true to isConnected method call after you see the log CLIENT_CONNECTED. Make sure that you provide enough time for event delivery which is usually very fast (just do not close client immediately so that the state does not change immediately). You can put a sleep after client connected and check to see if the listener state is connected.

Comment: I can see in the logs CLIENT_CONNECTED information. It is connected because I've added executor which have scheduled check for isConnected and trying to put and get data from cluster - isConnected is always 'false' no matter how many time has passed but the data is always put and get properly. It is just a matter of invalid state of isConnected method.
@Ozan Kılıç - sorry, but you are not right - the client is connected

Comment: @ishan demir - I will share you the logs

Answer (score 1):

All logs from Hazelcast client running:

```
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:42 PM com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] A non-empty group password is configured for the Hazelcast client. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.11, clients with the same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentication) will be accepted to a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed completely in a future release.
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientInvocationService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Running with 2 response threads, dynamic=false
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:43 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] HazelcastClient 3.12.1 (20190611 - 0a0ee66) is STARTING
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:43 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] HazelcastClient 3.12.1 (20190611 - 0a0ee66) is STARTED
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:44 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:44 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Trying to connect to cluster with name: hazelcast-cache-group
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:44 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Trying to connect to [FFFFFFFFF]:PORTXXXX as owner member
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:44 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Setting ClientConnection{alive=true, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/CLIENT-IP:58235->FFFFFFFFF/IPFFF:PORTXXXX}, remoteEndpoint=[FFFFFFFFF]:PORTXXXX, lastReadTime=2019-07-02 14:00:44.898, lastWriteTime=2019-07-02 14:00:44.711, closedTime=never, connected server version=3.12.1} as owner with principal ClientPrincipal{uuid='8090fecb-294f-4a4a-9da7-168bf0a7faff', ownerUuid='TOKEN-FFFFFFFFF'}
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:44 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Authenticated with server [FFFFFFFFF]:PORTXXXX, server version:3.12.1 Local address: /CLIENT-IP:58235
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] 

Members [6] {
    Member [AAAAAAAAA]:PORTXXXX - TOKEN-AAAAAAAAA
    Member [BBBBBBBBB]:PORTXXXX - TOKEN-BBBBBBBBB
    Member [CCCCCCCCC]:PORTXXXX - TOKEN-CCCCCCCCC
    Member [DDDDDDDDD]:PORTXXXX - TOKEN-DDDDDDDDD
    Member [EEEEEEEEE]:PORTXXXX - TOKEN-EEEEEEEEE
    Member [FFFFFFFFF]:PORTXXXX - TOKEN-FFFFFFFFF
}

Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] HazelcastClient 3.12.1 (20190611 - 0a0ee66) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Authenticated with server [AAAAAAAAA]:PORTXXXX, server version:3.12.1 Local address: /CLIENT-IP:58238
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Authenticated with server [BBBBBBBBB]:PORTXXXX, server version:3.12.1 Local address: /CLIENT-IP:58236
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Authenticated with server [CCCCCCCCC]:PORTXXXX, server version:3.12.1 Local address: /CLIENT-IP:58237
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Authenticated with server [EEEEEEEEE]:PORTXXXX, server version:3.12.1 Local address: /CLIENT-IP:58240
Jul 02, 2019 2:00:45 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager
INFO: hz.client_0 [hazelcast-cache-group] [3.12.1] Authenticated with server [DDDDDDDDD]:PORTXXXX, server version:3.12.1 Local address: /CLIENT-IP:58239
```